# Interpreting probability of an outcome

Tags: probability

Let's say you have a bag containing 4 balls, 1 of which is red and the 3 remaining are blue. Let our experiment be drawing one ball and recording the color, then putting the ball back in the bag. Then, the probability of drawing a red ball is 1/4 (25%). But, what exactly does 1/4 mean?

Does it mean that if you were to perform the same experiment four times, you are 100% guaranteed to get one red ball out of the four times? Or does it just mean "there is a 1/4 chance of getting a red ball per experiment"?

What is the correct interpretation of this probability? How do you interpret probability in general?

Comment: The second meaning is what we generally use. So if you do this experiment, say $1000$ times you would _expect_ to get a red ball _around_ $250$ times.

Comment: ok, so it's an expectation or an approximation and not a definite outcome, correct?

Comment: Yes. Normally you expect a head once in every two tosses but _sometimes_ (the chances are really low) you may not get a head in a hundred or even a thousand tosses! It is an approximation.

Comment: Drawing k red balls with n draws has a probability of $C(n,k)3^{n-k}/4^n$.  For "one red ball out of the four times", this is $C(4,1)3^3/4^4=27/64\approx42\%$.  This is the most likely thing to happen with four draws, but is far short of "100% guaranteed".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact meaning is that you know in advance there is 1 red ball out of 4 balls in the bag and when reaching in there is no way to tell which is red.  In practice it means that if you repeat the experiment many times you will pick the red ball approximately 1/4 of the time.

Comment: This is the frequentist interpretation of probability. Equally valid is the Bayesian view which interprets probability as the lack of knowledge one has about a system.

Answer (score 0):

The question of "How do you interpret probability in general?" is quite an important one. The most commonly used one agrees with your expression of ' "there is a 1/4 chance of getting a red ball per experiment" ', though is solely defined in terms of sizes of sets. (Note: this is perhaps a more abstract one than you will see in other answers)

The most common way to interpret it is in terms of sizes; we give each outcome of an experiment some number associated to how likely it is to happen. For this particular example, let's number our balls as 1, 2, 3, 4, and let's say ball number 4 is red (and the others are blue). From this pull-balls-out-of-the-bag experiment, there are then 4 outcomes {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}}. Now, since balls are indistinguishable when they are in the basket, we give them equal sizes. Now, we also want it to be the case that all the sizes sum up to 1 (This is just some nice normalization). As such, we assign each of them a "size" of 1/4. This measure of size is what is known as probability.

Now, from (mostly) this definition, it is (by long and arduous arguments) implied that if you pull from such a bag infinitely many times, a fourth of the time you will pull the red ball.